# Remove lines in a text file through batch

Tags: batch-file, text

I am looking for a batch command that can remove a line in a text file

```
John Doe has joined chat
Bob has joined chat
John Doe has left chat
```

Instead of having it like that, it will be like:

Before:

```
John Doe has joined chat
Bob has joined chat
```

After:

```
Bob has joined chat
John Doe has left chat
```

It will remove the "John Doe has joined chat" part and only has the leaving message. This will clean up the text file and keep it from getting too big. It could be like:

```
remline if include %USERNAME%
echo %USERNAME% has left chat >> users.dat
```

But "remline" is not a command as far as I know.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
findstr /v /b /L /c:"%username% " users.dat>tempfile.dat
move /y tempfile.dat users.dat >nul
```

should remove the line as you wish. The `findstr` finds all lines that `/v` do not `/b` at the beginning of the line `/L` literally `/c:"..."` contain this string.

Note that to the string to be eliminated I've deliberately added a space. This means that if you have users `Fred` and `Fred Two` then removing `Fred` won't affect the `Fred Two` records.